# .NET Core: why WaitHandle.SignalAndWait throws PlatformNotSupportedException on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, synchronization, .net-core

Have anyone an idea why WaitHandle's method 
`public static bool SignalAndWait(WaitHandle toSignal, WaitHandle toWaitOn, TimeSpan timeout, bool exitContext)` throws PlatformNotSupportedException on Linux?

Also it'd be helpful to know whether any analog exists (besides two subsequent calls `toSignal.Set` + `toWaitOn.WaitOne`).

Comment: @Olaf nothing unclear in the exception name, my question was about why `SignalAndWait` cannot be supported on Linux.

Comment: That's clearly not what you ask. Please next time safe our time and be clear about what you _mean_. And asking for the motivation is typically POB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: `WaitHandle.SignalAndWait` was added to .NET Core 2.1: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/16383

---

Original Answer:

Lets take a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/282f350b0c78c858ddef9c3c4cdcf0ea68a97e72/src/mscorlib/src/System/Threading/WaitHandle.cs#L441-L449):

```
throw new PlatformNotSupportedException(SR.Arg_PlatformNotSupported); // https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/10441
```

The issue it links to is [coreclr #10441](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/10441). This contains some insights:

> We believe this is possible to implement for Unix but it's a low priority as the API is flawed and it has extremely low usage.
>
> we ... determined that it’s not worth doing at the time.
>
> I would expect it to be used very rarely

So it looks like the developers gave it a low priority (because they think this is a bad API and has very low usage) and didn't implement it. If you file a bug in coreclr, that would provide them with the usage data and may convince them that this API is worth implementing fully.